# Why is my regex expression returning None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list

I have a python 3 code that is utilizing regex expressions to extract certain parts of sequences.

```
import re

seqs = """>UDW38231.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFS
NVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASIEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLIIV
NNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLDVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGK
QGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLL
ALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCT
LKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCV
ADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYN
YKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNG
VEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFN
FNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGT
NTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYEC
DIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISV
TTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVF
AQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLG
DIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQM
AYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLFSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTL
VKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASA
NLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAIC
HDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQ
PELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQE
LGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSE
PVLKGVKLHYT
>UDW38242.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFS
NVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLLIV
NNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLDVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGK
QGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLL
ALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCT
LKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCV
ADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYN
YKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNG
VEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFN
FNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGT
NTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYEC
DIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISV
TTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVF
AQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLG
DIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQM
AYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTL
VKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASA
NLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAIC
HDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQ
PELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQE
LGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAILMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSE
PVLKGVKLHYT
"""
seq2 = seqs.replace("\n","")
list = seq2.split(">")
list.pop(0)

rbd = re.finditer(r'RV[NVSFGYLPTAKRICDQEWH]{219,219}NF',seqs.replace("\n", ""))

for x in rbd:
    indication = re.search(r'^.*\(\+\)', x.group(0))
    print(f"{indication} has the rbd domain{x.span()}\n")
```

My code gives me the output

```
None has the rbd domain(369, 592)

None has the rbd domain(1693, 1916)
```

Instead I should be getting

```
UDW38231.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+) has the rbd domain(369, 592)

UDW38242.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+) has the rbd domain(1693, 1916)
```

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong? I think my mistake lies in the regex expression for capturing everything before (+) for each string, and it can't find it thus it is returning None, but I'm not sure

Comment: What is the value of `x.group(0)`? It's "RVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCVADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYNYKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNGVEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNF" and that doesn't contain `(+)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this implementation does what you're after

```
import re


seqs = """>UDW38231.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFS
NVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASIEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLIIV
NNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLDVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGK
QGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLL
ALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCT
LKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCV
ADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYN
YKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNG
VEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFN
FNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGT
NTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYEC
DIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISV
TTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVF
AQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLG
DIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQM
AYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLFSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTL
VKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASA
NLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAIC
HDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQ
PELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQE
LGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAIVMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSE
PVLKGVKLHYT
>UDW38242.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)
MFVFLVLLPLVSSQCVNLRTRTQLPPAYTNSFTRGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQDLFLPFFS
NVTWFHAIHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFNDGVYFASTEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLDSKTQSLLIV
NNATNVVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLDVYYHKNNKSWMESGVYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDLEGK
QGNFKNLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHTPINLVRDLPQGFSALEPLVDLPIGINITRFQTLL
ALHRSYLTPGDSSSGWTAGAAAYYVGYLQPRTFLLKYNENGTITDAVDCALDPLSETKCT
LKSFTVEKGIYQTSNFRVQPTESIVRFPNITNLCPFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRKRISNCV
ADYSVLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVIRGDEVRQIAPGQTGKIADYN
YKLPDDFTGCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYNYRYRLFRKSNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGSKPCNG
VEGFNCYFPLQSYGFQPTNGVGYQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATVCGPKKSTNLVKNKCVNFN
FNGLTGTGVLTESNKKFLPFQQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTLEILDITPCSFGGVSVITPGT
NTSNQVAVLYQGVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGSNVFQTRAGCLIGAEHVNNSYEC
DIPIGAGICASYQTQTNSRRRARSVASQSIIAYTMSLGAENSVAYSNNSIAIPTNFTISV
TTEILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYICGDSTECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRALTGIAVEQDKNTQEVF
AQVKQIYKTPPIKDFGGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKRSFIEDLLFNKVTLADAGFIKQYGDCLG
DIAARDLICAQKFNGLTVLPPLLTDEMIAQYTSALLAGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPFAMQM
AYRFNGIGVTQNVLYENQKLIANQFNSAIGKIQDSLSSTASALGKLQNVVNQNAQALNTL
VKQLSSNFGAISSVLNDILSRLDKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTYVTQQLIRAAEIRASA
NLAATKMSECVLGQSKRVDFCGKGYHLMSFPQSAPHGVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFTTAPAIC
HDGKAHFPREGVFVSNGTHWFVTQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFVSGNCDVVIGIVNNTVYDPLQ
PELDSFKEELDKYFKNHTSPDVDLGDISGINASVVNIQKEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLIDLQE
LGKYEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAGLIAILMVTIMLCCMTSCCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFDEDDSE
PVLKGVKLHYT
"""
pattern = re.compile(r'[^>]*\(\+\)')  # use char classing to avoid capturing '>'

for i, x in enumerate(rbd):
    indications = re.findall(pattern, seqr))  # use findall to get a list of matches
    print(f"{indications[i]} has the rbd domain{x.span()}\n")
```

In my testing, 'indications' captured `['UDW38231.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)', 'UDW38242.1 |surface glycoprotein|MS|GenBank|ssRNA(+)']`